# xCode Storyboard, Tab bar item image size

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

As seen in the image. The tab bar image is too large.

I followed apple's guidelines, @1x = 30px @2x = 60px @3x = 90px

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried resizing in size inspector??

Comment: I dont see any resize inspector. Which tab is this in?

Comment: The tab with the ruler

Answer (score 1):

**Please refer UITabBar icon size:**

[image: UITabBar icon size]

Answer (score 0):

I remember tab bar image icon size should be 25px